# How to install gnome-tweak-tool in Gnome Shell GIT?

Tags: gnome

Does anyone know how to use gnome-tweak-tool with gnome shell built from GIT? I installed gnome tweak tool via ppa, but it gives errors while trying to start it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the errors you mention!

Comment: this is the output i get when executing gnome-tweak-tool: http://pastebin.com/xSm472RT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get the build dependencies of gnome-tweak tool

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then get the repo

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then go inside the directory and run configure

```
cd gnome-tweak-tool
./autogen.sh
make
make install
```

Please avoid --prefix or else it will overwrite the version present from the PPA.

Then start the tool using

```
/usr/local/bin/gnome-tweak-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using the latest G-S from git you might want to use G-Tweak from git too!
do a full update and dist-upgrade, sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
then cd git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-tweak-tool then do cd gnome-tweak-tool then ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
most of this is from posts by Andrew @ webupd8 and applied by me :-)